# How to use JSH to change an element within another element's event

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to alter element when form is submitted without sending ajax request. And can't figure out how to write it properly and generate code that I want.

In cakePHP view I have:

```
$this->Js->get('#testForm')->event('submit', $this->Js->get('#fastRegisterForm')->effect('show'));
```

And it generates:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fastRegisterForm").bind("submit", function (event) {
        $("#fastRegisterForm").show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

And I want to have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#testForm").bind("submit", function (event) {
        $("#fastRegisterForm").show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should setup it in a different way.

```
$eventCode = $this->Js->get('#fastRegisterForm')->effect('show');

$this->Js->get('#testForm')->event('submit', $eventCode);
```

Cake might be getting "confused" when you call another `js->get` inside of a `js->get`

Comment: This is solution for my question. But anyway I will write everything in jQuery. JSHelper sucks a little.

Comment: Typically, I use jQuery code and not JsHelper. I feel I have more flexibility as well as I take that opportunity to learn a little bit more jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Forget JsHelper and write jquery code yourself.

Comment: It is good to know both ways though. However, if you are having problems, I agree with you, just stick with jQuery coding since all Cake will do is translate the php code supplied to it into jQuery code.

Comment: There isn't any real need to know how to use the JsHelper. Apart from doing basic things it will generally hinder you instead of increasing your dev speed. Using a php wrapper to generate jquery code doesn't really make sense when you can directly write jquery code faster and more efficiently. That's why JsHelper is going to be removed in CakePHP 3.0

Comment: I seldom use JsHelper if not never. Writing directly in jQuery at every moment it is needed improves your skill anyway. So why not! I use jQuery directly for my CakePHP programming as well.